# Creating reusable modules with spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, reusability

I'm new to Spring and Spring boot and was looking if it was possible to create reusable modules using Spring boot. For instance, is it possible to create a project in Spring boot, say UserModule, that handles all user related details like registration, authentication and then create other projects, say App1 and App2, which can use UserModule as a dependency? The idea is to avoid re-defining the user related entities, services and controller every time a new project is created. So far I've only found [Multi Module Project](https://spring.io/guides/gs/multi-module/), but I'm not sure how that could be used to create reusable modules. The multi module project only creates separate pom file for each module, but I'm not sure if and how that could be reused in new projects.

Comment: use pom as a dependency in a another pom

Comment: You just need add to your pom as dependency.

Comment: Why would you need Spring Boot for that? You can do that just with plain Java already.

Comment: I tried packaging one application as a jar and use that jar as a dependency in a second project (not using multi module), but I cannot invoke the services in the first project from the second project. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Spring supports multi module projects. Only convention required is declaring module and parent project in pom.xml. Go through sample pom.xml [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/multi-module/), Spring portal has very good documentation and example of same.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-multi-module</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>library</module>
        <module>application</module>
    </modules>

</project>
```

Comment: Doesn't this require library and application directories to be inside a parent directory having a parent pom file? What I'm looking for is for application2, which is in a separate directory outside of the parent directory, to be able to use library. Would that be possible?

Comment: This is possible if you are using module/project as dependency

Comment: I tried creating a new project called **notification** that only has a **NotificationService** with a single method. I did `mvn package` to create a jar file for this project and then `mvn install:install-file` so that the jar is now available in my .m2 directory. Next, I created another project called **tasks** in a separate directory and in its pom.xml, I added the **notification jar** as a dependency. Then  from the **TaskController**, I tried accessing the **NotificationService**, but I'm not able to do that. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: In the pom.xml file of **tasks**, I have

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.testmodule</groupId>
 <artifactId>notification</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

Now, in **TaskController**, when I try
    import com.testmodule.notification.*;
I get 
    The import com.testmodule cannot be resolved.